# Excel to DataTable Insert

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to insert into a database from Excel, and I've got all values from Excel. When I insert into my database I get Factal Exception. How do I recover from this exception?

```
            MySqlCommand commd = new MySqlCommand();
            commd.Connection = OpenConnection();

            commd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO sqa_tracking(IID,STARTDATE,ENDDATE,WEEK,SUPPLIER,LINENO,ORDER_ID,BRCARID,PAGE_FIRST,PAGE_LAST,PAGE_COUNT,ARTICLE_NO,COUNT_LINENO,TOTAL_NR_OF_ITEMS,CAR_SUPPLIER,CONTENT_PROVIDER_NAME,MANIFESTATION,FACTOR,UNITS,DATE_OF_SUBMISSION,UNITS_KEY,COUNT_UNITS_KEY,TOTAL_NR_OF_UNITS,ERRORS,KPI_ERRORS,OBII_ELEMENT,CAR_FIELD_NAME,ERROR_TYPE,WRONG_CAPTURE_IN_FILE,CORRECT_CAPTURE_WOULD_BE,REPEATING_IN_CAR,SOURCE_FILE_TYPE,FULL_AUTOM_CONV,ERROR_IN_SOURCE_FILE,ROOT_CAUSE_OF_THE_ERROR,PREVENTIVE_MEASURES,DATE_OF_IMPLEMENTATION,DATE_OF_TRANSMISSION,VALIDATED) VALUES (@IID,@STARTDATE,@ENDDATE,@WEEK,@SUPPLIER,@LINENO,@ORDER_ID,@BRCARID,@PAGE_FIRST,@PAGE_LAST,@PAGE_COUNT,@ARTICLE_NO,@COUNT_LINENO,@TOTAL_NR_OF_ITEMS,@CAR_SUPPLIER,@CONTENT_PROVIDER_NAME,@MANIFESTATION,@FACTOR,@UNITS,@DATE_OF_SUBMISSION,@UNITS_KEY,@COUNT_UNITS_KEY,@TOTAL_NR_OF_UNITS,@ERRORS,@KPI_ERRORS,@OBII_ELEMENT,@CAR_FIELD_NAME,@ERROR_TYPE,@WRONG_CAPTURE_IN_FILE,@CORRECT_CAPTURE_WOULD_BE,@REPEATING_IN_CAR,@SOURCE_FILE_TYPE,@FULL_AUTOM_CONV,@ERROR_IN_SOURCE_FILE,@ROOT_CAUSE_OF_THE_ERROR,@PREVENTIVE_MEASURES,@DATE_OF_IMPLEMENTATION,@DATE_OF_SUBMISSION,@VALIDATED) ";


            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@STARTDATE", StartDate);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ENDDATE", EndDate);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WEEK", Week);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SUPPLIER", Supplier);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LINENO", LineNo);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ORDER_ID", ORDERID);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BRCARID", "");
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PAGE_FIRST", PageFirst);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PAGE_LAST", Pagelast);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PAGE_COUNT", Pagecount);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ARTICLE_NO", ArticleNo);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COUNT_LINENO", COUNTLineNo);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TOTAL_NR_OF_ITEMS", Totalnrofitems);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CAR_SUPPLIER", CARSupplier);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CONTENT_PROVIDER_NAME", ContentProvidename);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MANIFESTATION", Manifestation);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FACTOR", AU);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UNITS", Units);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE_OF_SUBMISSION", Dateoftransmission);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UNITS_KEY", unitskey);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COUNT_UNITS_KEY", COUNTunitskey);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ERRORS", Errors);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KPI_ERRORS", KPIErrors);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OBII_ELEMENT", OBIIElement);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CAR_FIELD_NAME", CARFieldname);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ERROR_TYPE", Errortype);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IID", IID);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WRONG_CAPTURE_IN_FILE", Wrongcaptureinfile);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CORRECT_CAPTURE_WOULD_BE", Correctcapturewouldbe);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REPEATING_IN_CAR", RepeatinginCAR);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SOURCE_FILE_TYPE", Sourcefiletype);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FULL_AUTOM_CONV", FulAutomConv);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ERROR_IN_SOURCE_FILE", Errorinsourcefile);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ROOT_CAUSE_OF_THE_ERROR", RootCauseoftheError);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PREVENTIVE_MEASURES", PreventiveMeasures);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE_OF_IMPLEMENTATION", DateofImplementation);
            commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VALIDATED", Validated);
            commd.ExecuteNonQuery();`
```

I used inline query and I got the parameter values from DataTable.

Comment: Paste here the exact exception and the line where it's thrown

Comment: Fatal error encountered during command execution in commd.ExecuteNonQuery(); line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always remember that fatal error occurred during command execution only because of incorrect parameters value name.

so correct the parameter value to avoid fetal errors during command execution
You have not provided parameter value for TOTAL_NR_OF_UNITS & DATE_OF_TRANSMISSION.

Also Please follow the order in your insert query and while adding parameters, makes it easier to troubleshoot.

```
commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TOTAL_NR_OF_UNITS",TotalNrOfUnits);
commd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE_OF_TRANSMISSION", DateOfTransmission);
```

Answer (score 0):

Either this . . .

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_insert  values (@id,@name,@Email,@City)");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(txtId.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txtboxCity.Text);
```

...or this...

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"insert into tbl_insert values(@name,@email,@add)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add", txtadd.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

...should work fine.